# MariaDB how to make an RMS function?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to make an RMS function on My MariaDB. I have found this topic: [Link](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/13/running-root-mean-square-sql-server/).

With this code:

```
WITH    nums AS
    (
    SELECT  value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderer) AS rn
    FROM    source
    ) 
SELECT  SQRT(AVG(POWER(np.value - nn.value, 2)))
FROM    nums np
JOIN    nums nn
ON      nn.rn = np.rn + 1
```

The problem is that the SQL standard Common Table Expressions (CTEs) is not supported for my version (10.1.18-MariaDB). The last one on the Archarm Linux the things is fix for the version 10.2.2: [MDEV-8308](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8308)

And I don't know how to do the same work in a different way. If someone can help.

Comment: Google "simulate lead lag in MySQL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` by creating an actual table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` that is the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then you can do a "self join" of that table to itself.  It's only a few keystrokes more than your CTE attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE nums (
    rn INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB
    SELECT value FROM source ORDER BY orderer;

SELECT  SQRT(AVG(POWER(np.value - nn.value, 2)))
    FROM nums AS np
    JOIN nums AS nn  ON nn.rn = np.rn + 1;
```

Notes:

- The `id` being defined in the `CREATE TABLE` will be in addition to `value` coming from the `SELECT.
- This assumes `auto_increment_increment = 1`.  If you are using Galera (etc), change the `+1` to `+ @@auto_increment_increment`.
- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` won't work because (until recently) you could not use that kind of temp table twice in the same query.  (Why?  Beats me!)